# Send and receive output via socket in python

Tags: python

I'm newbie for python. And I would like to python can do following things:
- Create socket (Done)
- Send specific commands over sockets (Done)
- Get the output of command on remotely machine (Not yet)

I'm stuck at the third one. If anyone can hep me, I'm really appreciated.

Comment: code? what have you tried? do you have an error you want resolved? this isn't a site for people to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have creating and sending then recv is just as simple.

```
 s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 host = 'www.stackoverflow.com';
 port = 80;
 remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname( host )
 s.connect((remote_ip , port))
 message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"
 s.sendall(message)
 reply = s.recv(4096)

 print reply
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty good explanation of TCP/IP communication with Python sockets:
https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html